# IntelliJ IDEA, always display the "Show Execution Point" button in the Service tool window

Tags: intellij-idea

In the Service tool window of IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2, I would like to always display the "Show Execution Point" button. Now, it is accessible only through the "More" button" (three vertical dots).

How can I do this ?[image]

Comment: Please try workaround from related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-302974

Answer (score 1):

You can add the "Show Execution Point" to the debug toolbar by:

1. Right click on a debug button (right click on empty space does nothing)
   [image]
2. Click "Customize toolbar"
   [image]
3. Click the plus sign (Add actions)
4. Find "Show Execution Point" in the list
   [image]